# jQuery change value input when drag the mouse up and down

Tags: jquery, mousemove, mousedown

how can I make an input type text change its value when you click inside it and drag the mouse up to increase the value and down to decrease the value. Only when the mouse moves up and down does the value change from the input (validate min y max) I have this but I can not make it work as a wish.

**[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/busixaqebo/edit?html,js,output)**

```
var clicking = false;
$('#change_value_up_down').mousedown(function(){
    clicking = true;
    $('.clickstatus').text('mousedown');
});
var i = 0;
var y = 0;
$('#change_value_up_down').mousemove(function(my){
    if(clicking === false) return;

    // change value
    y = my.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    $(this).val(y);

    // Mouse click + moving logic here
    $('.movestatus').text('mouse moved ' + i);
  i++;
});
$('.selector').mouseup(function() {
  i = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/KrtVu/143/)**.

I think you want somethig like the following example.

```
var down = false;
var my = $("#change_value_up_down").offset().top;
var counter;

$(document).mousedown(function() {
  down = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
  down = false;  
  clearInterval(counter);
});

$("#change_value_up_down").mouseenter(function(e) {
  clearInterval(counter);
})

$("#change_value_up_down").mouseout(function(e) {
  var current_value = $(this).val();
  var self = $(this);

  if(down) {
    if(e.clientY<my) {
       counter = setInterval(function(){
          self.val(current_value++);
       },300);
    }else{
      counter = setInterval(function(){
          self.val(current_value--);
       },300);
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var down = false;
var speed = 100;
var my = $("#change_value_up_down").offset().top;
var counter;

$(document).mousedown(function() {
  down = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
  down = false;  
  clearInterval(counter);
});
$("#change_value_up_down").mouseenter(function(e) {
  clearInterval(counter);
})

$("#change_value_up_down").mouseout(function(e) {
  var current_value = $(this).val();
  var self = $(this);
  
  if(down) {
    if(e.clientY<my) {
       counter = setInterval(function(){
         self.val(current_value++);
       },speed);
    }else{
      counter = setInterval(function(){
         self.val(current_value--);
       },speed);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<input type="text" value=5 id="change_value_up_down" size="2" style="cursor:n-resize;"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but when you drag the mouse up it counts automatically, you should stop when you release the click

Comment: Must stop when the click is not pressed, for example does not happen http://recordit.co/2tsvYFFw5h

Comment: I can't reproduce the same error, in my screen when the mouse not clicked the `mouseup` event will fire and the counter wil be stopped by `clearInterval(counter)`, check please if the fiddle will give you the same issue.

Comment: This is the effect I want to cause, increasing and decreasing the input value only if it moves from top to bottom but pressed the click from input http://recordit.co/YJovptdj9f

Comment: This works fine, but only in firefox, but in chrome does not work the same, as it could be debugged https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/ggqzb27f/#

Comment: The last fiddle not working with the click inside input just by `mouseover` the field it'll start counting instead my post here works fine for me as your last _recordit_ shows in the both firefox/chrome , I'm not sure what's the problem in your side (try to updated the browser and recheck).

Comment: hi, again, i did it but it only works fine in firefox, I have problems running Chrome, could anyone tell me what the problem is with Chrome? jsfiddle.net/iLen/bacx5qem

Comment: I have problems even with the script that is this http://jsfiddle.net/iLen/bacx5qem/ It only works in firefox, but it does not work the same in Chrome

Comment: So post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgxbr3x2/6/) :

JS:

```
    var clicking = false;
        $('this').click(function () {
            clicking = false;
        });
        $('#change_value_up_down').mouseover(function () {
            clicking = true;
        });
        var i = 0;
        var y = 0;
        $(this).mousemove(function(my){
            if(clicking === false) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                // change value
                if (my.pageY <= $('#change_value_up_down').offset().top + $('#change_value_up_down').css('width').replace('px', '')/10) 
                {
                    y = parseInt($('#change_value_up_down').val()) +1 ;
                    $('.movestatus').text('plus');
                    }
                else
                {
                    y =  parseInt($('#change_value_up_down').val()) -1;
                    $('.movestatus').text('minus');
                    }
                $('#change_value_up_down').val(parseInt(y));  
                // Mouse click + moving logic here
                //$('.movestatus').text('mouse moved ' + i);
                i++;
            }
        });
        $('#change_value_up_down').mouseup(function(e) {
            clicking = false;
            //e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('.selector').mouseup(function(e) {
            i = 0;
        });
```

Comment: It should only increase or decrease when the click is pressed and moved from top to bottom, when not pressed should not do any action

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/ggqzb27f/#&togetherjs=x6the0lAf6)

Comment: This is fine but I would like it to only increase when the click is pressed, because currently it is doing when you move the mouse up and down without being pressed the click (I think it's in the mousedown event when everything should run)

Comment: This is the effect I want to cause, increasing and decreasing the input value only if it moves from top to bottom but pressed the click from input http://recordit.co/YJovptdj9f

Comment: This works fine, but only in firefox, but in chrome does not work the same, as it could be debugged https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/ggqzb27f/#

Comment: As per [recordit.co/YJovptdj9f](http://recordit.co/YJovptdj9f) this is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/3td2s0w8/). May it helps!

Comment: hi, again, i did it but it only works fine in firefox, I have problems running Chrome, could anyone tell me what the problem is with Chrome? https://jsfiddle.net/iLen/bacx5qem/

Answer (score 0):

The answer I could find in a posts of another language that it makes, works perfectly for the moment.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34265/jquery-funcion-que-permita-a-n-numeros-de-inputs-hacer-incremento-decremento-por/